# Value of $h$ in a vector to make that vector a linear combination of the span of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question that gives two vectors and a third vector with a variable and it asks what the variable must be so that the vector is a linear combination of the span of the other two vectors.  e.g.:

Let $\ a_1=\left[ \begin{array}{}
\ \ \ 1 \\
\ \ \ 3 \\
-1 \end{array} \right] 
$, $a_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{}
-5 \\
-8 \\\ \ 2\end{array} \right]$
and $b = \left[ \begin{array}{}
\ \ \ 3 \\
-5 \\\ \ h\end{array} \right]$

From my understanding of what we've done so far, to say $b$ is a linear combination of $a_1$ and $a_2$ means that the augmented matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{}
\ \ \ 1 & -5 & \ \ \ 3\\
\ \ \ 3 & -8 & -5\\
-1 & \ \ \ 2 & \ \ \ h\end{array} \right]$ has a solution.

So I started doing row operations to put it in Echelon form:

$3R_1-R_2$ followed by $R_1 + R_3$ produces:

$\left[ \begin{array}{}
\ \ \ 1 & -5 & \ \ \ \ \ 3\\
\ \ \ 0 & -7 &\  \ \ 14\\
\ \ \ 0 & -3 & (3 + h)\end{array} \right]$

So I thought that to make sure this matrix has to have a solution, the last row has to equal $3+h$ so I said $-3 = 3+h$ meaning $h = -6$ but the answer in my book says $h = 3$.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also as a bonus, can anyone look at my LaTex code and see if there is an easier way to make matrix columns line up?  I'm just using escaped spaces which is tedious.  Is there a command?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you put it you should have made *column* operations. I propose to change the matrix and still make row operations:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&3&\!\!-1\\
\!\!-5&\!\!-8&2\\3&\!\!-5&h\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&3&\!\!-1\\
0&7&\!\!-3\\0&\!\!-14&h+3\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3+2R_2}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&3&\!\!-1\\
0&7&\!\!-3\\0&0&h-3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: We haven't really talked about column operations in my class, but your last matrix makes sense using the way I thought it was supposed to be done - $0 = h - 3$ would have to be true so $h = 3$.  How do you know to set the matrix up that way as opposed to just combining the vectors?

Comment: @Sabien As you put it and did, it is as if you were trying to find out whether $\;(-1,2,h)\;$ is a linear combination of $\;(1,-5,3)\;,\;(3,-8,-5)\;$ . It doesn't really affect the outcome of the question "for what values of $\;h\;$ ...etc", yet if you want to find out the exact linear combination it does.

Comment: Ok.  I just need to review the book more I guess - I thought you can just combine the vectors into an augmented matrix.  I wasn't aware you have to flip the columns into rows.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The tree vectors are linearly independent if
$$
\det
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
1& -5&3\\
3&-8&-5\\
-1&2&h
\end{array}
\right] =0
$$
I.E.
$$
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
-8&-5\\
2&h
\end{array}
\right |
+5
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
3&-5\\
-1&h
\end{array}
\right |
+3
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
3&-8\\
-1&2
\end{array}
\right |
=0
$$
that give $7h=21 \Rightarrow h=3$

Comment: That seems to be correct according to the book, but how do you get to $7h = 21$?

Comment: You can see my edit.

Comment: I don't know how to do that math (I know determinant but I don't know how to set it up with a 3x3 matrix) but it seems to work.  I'm sure we will get to this at some point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$3R_1-R_2$ (Manipulation of the 2nd row) leads to the following new 2nd row: $(0,7,-14)$ (there was a mistake in the signs). $R_1+R_3$ is done right.

Comment: I don't think so because $-15 - (-8) = -7$ and 9 - (-5) = 14.. I don't see how you get reversed signs.

Answer (score 0):

b can be expressed as $\vec{b} = P\vec{a_1} + Q\vec{a_2}$
\begin{align}
P-5Q &= 3 \\
3P-8Q &= -5
\end{align}
solve this system of equations (using whatever method you prefer)
\begin{align}
P &= -7 \\
Q &= -2
\end{align}
so $h = -P+2Q = 3$